# RXJS Angular - Error handling using .subscribe and Observable

Tags: typescript, error-handling, rxjs, httpclient, rxjs-observables

I have a backend api to create new product. The frontend angular code needs to call a backend API. How to carry out error handling using ** .subscribe**. I'm using *HTTPClient* and using *Observable* and been reading about how RXJS utilizes error handling,

The app should call it as Observable and .subscribe().

the api /create should handle success and failure(error) 
- If API returns 200: it should print success
- If API returns 400, should throw an error

**pseudo code**

````
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

ID = 'foo';
            this.http.post('/api/create', {
                productName: this.form.value.productName,
                productValue: this.form.value.productValue,
            }).subscribe(
                resp => this.onSubmitSuccess(resp), err => this.onSubmitFailure(err)
            );


private onSubmitSuccess(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        this.ID = resp.ID;
        this.submitSuccess = true;
        this.submitFailed = false;
    }

    private onSubmitFailure(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        this.submitFailed = true;
        this.submitSuccess = false;
    }  ```
````

Answer (score 4):

The earlier versions used to be like:

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
 data =>
 {
   //do something
 },
 error =>
 {
   //handle error
 }
);
```

With the latest versions, they have deprecated this format. Now you have to do:

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
 {
   next: (data) => 
   {
     //do something
   },
   error: (error) =>
   {
     //handle error
   }
 }
);
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

[Handling request errors](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors).
It is official Angular documentation

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

Comment: This example does not use .subscribe

Comment: sorry, I missed that part. the code inside 'subscribe' function is a smell. `pipes` are way more flexible and should be used unless it's unavoidable. once you get used to RxJs, you totally forget about it (: here is one of the arguments: https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/05/async-pipe-versus-subscribe-in-angular.html

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot use `async` pipe and must use subscribe, using `pipe` operators is best practice and allows you to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. It is more functional to use the operators to put logic, as subscribe should be only used to show that that the stream is being observed. It could be something like this:

```
  ID = 'foo';
  onDestroy = new Subject<boolean>();

  this.http.post('/api/create', {
      productName: this.form.value.productName,
      productValue: this.form.value.productValue,
  }).pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      onSubmitFailure(err);
      return of(err);
    }),
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
    tap(resp => onSubitSuccess(resp)),
  ).subscribe();

  onSubmitSuccess(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
      this.ID = resp.ID;
      this.submitSuccess = true;
      this.submitFailed = false;
  }

  onSubmitFailure(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
      this.submitFailed = true;
      this.submitSuccess = false;
  } 

  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.onDestroy$.next(true);
      this.onDestroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
```